# Criação de classes em C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e preciso criar uma classe interna. Sou obrigado a criar um .cpp e um .h?

Comment: Depende de onde você quer aplicar essa classe. Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Tenho um programa para realizar alguns cálculos que dependem de outros cálculos com base em uma esfera. Pensei em criar uma classe que armazene o raio desta e que calculasse, por meio de métodos, algumas informações que sejam interessantes, como perímetro, área e volume.

Comment: Não, vc não é obrigado, mas isso facilita algumas coisas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O local onde você definir a classe vai influenciar basicamente o acesso às definições por outros trechos do código, pois para o compilador isso não fará muita diferença.

No entanto, deve considerar que quando você define as funções no próprio corpo da classe *geralmente*, dependendo das configurações, o compilador tratará essas funções como `inline` (na verdade, você apenas sugere ao compilador que a faça `inline`, ele decidirá se é viável).

---

Se você implementá-la só no `.cpp` você poderá utilizá-la como se estivesse feito num arquivo de cabeçalho `.h`, mas não poderá reaproveitá-la em outro trecho do código se precisar.

Se você definir tudo no `main.cpp`, por exemplo, seria tipo isso:

```
#include <iostream>

const float PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

class Circulo
{
    public:
        Circulo(float raio)
        {
            m_raio = raio;
        }

        float getRaio() const
        {
            return m_raio;
        }

        void setRaio(float raio)
        {
            m_raio = raio;
        }

        float getArea() const
        {
            return PI * m_raio * m_raio;
        }

        float getPerimetro() const
        {
            return PI * m_raio * 2.0f;
        }

    private:
        float m_raio;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Circulo circ(5.0f);

    std::cout << "Area = " << circ.getArea() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Perimetro = " << circ.getPerimetro() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Agora se você definir a classe `Circulo` em um `.h`, você pode reaproveitar o código em outros arquivos. E no caso do `main.cpp` ficaria assim:

```
#include "circulo.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Circulo circ(5.0f);

    std::cout << "Area = " << circ.getArea() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Perimetro = " << circ.getPerimetro() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A questão é se você vai precisar reutilizar a classe que te gerou essa dúvida em outro local. Se sim, é recomendável fazer uma definição num cabeçalho para ela.